# Как запустить код в открытом файле Пайтон через Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Я запускаю `файл.py` через другой `файл.py` (командой `os.startfile(r'путь_к_файлу.py')`).
У меня запускаться `Thonny` с открытым этим файлом, но сам код не запускается.
Вопрос, как мне запустить код в открытом файле Пайтон через пайтон?

Comment: Попробуйте прямо указать, что питоном он должен запускаться, что-то типа `os.startfile(r'python путь_к_файлу.py')` ну или нужно смотреть доку на `startfile` как там запустить что-то и передать параметры

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так получилось

```
exec(open("Script1.py").read())
```